# Displaying Custom Taxonomy without a hyperlink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I would love some help on how I can best display the custom taxonomy of a post as text only (and not as link within an  tag).

I have a small template file that is called by a few other pages, and the job of that template file is to render a citation for an article - here's the complete code:

```
<div class="ehp_citation_block">
   <h6><strong><?php the_category(' | '); ?></strong></h6>
   <span class="alignright"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ehp_volumes' ); ?></span>
   <?php the_field('ehp_citation'); ?>
   </div>
```

This portion of that php file:

```
<?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ehp_volumes' ); ?>
```

Does its job in displaying the taxonomy - but it is wrapped in a hyperlink. Is there an attribute that will just return the text of taxonomy? Do I need to use a variable instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_the_terms` instead of `the_terms`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ehp_volumes' );
$term_count = count( $terms );
if ( $term_count > 0 && ! wp_error( $terms ) ) {
  $terms = array_values( $terms ); // reset keys for easier looping. by default the key matches the term id
  for( $i = 0; $i <= $term_count; $i++ ) {
    $output.= $terms[$i]->name;
    $output.= ( $i < $term_count-1 ? ', ' : null ); // add commas between terms, but not to the last one
  }
  echo $output;
  unset( $output );
}
unset( $terms, $term_count );
```

Below is an updated suggestion based on comments (need ability to order terms DESC). To accomplish this use `wp_get_object_terms` instead of `get_the_terms` since it accepts a third parameter allowing you to filter and order the results.

I actually like this one better - much simpler.

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms(
  $post->ID,
  'ehp_volumes',
  array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'names'
  )
);
echo ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ? implode( ', ', $terms ) : 'null' );
unset( $terms );
```

Comment: Joey - thanks! Would that code go inside a php statement? I'm not sure how to implement your solution.

Comment: I've updated the script on how to output the terms. This would replace what you have currently in span.alignright.

Comment: Awesome. Just put that in, and it is working. 

If you care to continue to lead me along on this problem, the solution you crafted creates another issue. The template file is being called ten times by the page (I'm using it to display a set of results), so it adds to the $terms variable every time. Can I null out the variable at the beginning?

Comment: Ah, sounds like we need to clear the `$term_count` and `$terms` vars as you suspected. I've updated my original answer to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome! Really appreciate the help, Joey.

Comment: I'm really learning alot from the solution you set up, btw. If I wanted to rearrange the resulting array of values to be descending - is there a way to do that in the php statement?

Comment: Hi Hal- I've updated the answer with an alternative option using `wp_get_object_terms` which accepts a third parameter for ordering. I actually like the simplicity of this solution better than my original. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh - that's awesome. Just put that up on our development box, and it works like a charm. Thanks!